# Display empty row using timeline from react-google-charts

Tags: reactjs, charts, google-visualization

I am using the timeline chart from react-google-charts and can't figure out how to display empty rows for which no data is available.

In the picture, you see that only Friday (a day for which I have data) is shown. But I also want to display Monday to Thursday.

[image]

I could add empty dummy rows (picture below) but even if the duration is 0 they are displayed with a bar. I would like the rows without available data to be completely empty.

[image]

I tried to include a dummy entry to every row and make it transparent. But I could only set the whole row to transparent which doesn't help me.

Do you have any hints?

Comment: Hey, I've seen some examples of this working, but I can't seem to get it to work with the current API (it may be broken, or have been removed, but please correct me if you figure out how to get it to work).

The trick is to add an additional column with the `role` of `style`, and add `'opacity: 0'` to the rows which you don't wish to display.

This technique is mentioned on the timeline documentation page, and links through to this page: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole

Sorry I couldn't get a working example, but it may help you in some way.

Comment: Thanks. Looks promising. I am gonna try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here, I use the `colors` option to make the `Adams` row transparent.

**EDIT** -- to make individual bars transparent, add unique bar labels.

you can use option `timeline.showBarLabels` to hide the bar labels, if needed...

see following working snippet...

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Category' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        dataTable.addRows([
          [ 'Washington', 'A', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Adams', 'B',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Adams', 'C',      new Date(1798, 0, 1),  new Date(1802, 1, 18) ],
          [ 'Jefferson', 'D',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

        chart.draw(dataTable, {
          colors: ['red', 'transparent', 'blue', 'green'],
          timeline: {showBarLabels: false}
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="timeline" style="height: 180px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT 2**

since transparent is not a valid color string using react,
you can use a style column role, instead of the colors option.

to make the bar transparent, set `opacity: 0;`.

see following working snippet...

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Category' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        dataTable.addRows([
          [ 'Washington', 'A', 'red', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Adams', 'B',      'opacity: 0;', new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Adams', 'C',      'blue', new Date(1798, 0, 1),  new Date(1802, 1, 18) ],
          [ 'Jefferson', 'D',  'green', new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

        chart.draw(dataTable, {
          timeline: {showBarLabels: false}
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="timeline" style="height: 180px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it looks good! Do you now how to make individual bars of a row transparent and not the whole row?

Comment: Seems like a good option but it doesn't work with react-google-charts lib. I get the error message: "transparent is not a valid color string."